# XSP Missing Libraries

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Last week I upgraded to Domino Designer v10.  Now I get the following error messages:

```
The import org.openntf cannot be resolved.
```

Opened the XSP properties in designer and noticed in the Page Generation tab that I am missing the `org.openntf.xsp.debugtoolbar.library`.

I have searched for hours on this and found nothing that will resolved it.  I looked at this posting https://openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=JGAR-B9QL8B but it didn't resolve the problem.

My local Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform points to `...Notes\framework\rcp\eclipse\` and `Notes\Data\workspace\applications\eclipse`.
The `org.openntf.xsp.debugtoolbar_1.1.0.201403092102.jar` file is in the later.

I reinstalled the XPages Debug Toolbar through Eclipse Update Site (9) database locally.

I have no idea what to do.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can help too: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/058650E080E352178525832B00519D2C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check File > Application > Application Management and make sure the plugin hasn't been set to disabled. Also Help > Support > View Log / View Trace for any errors. See https://www.intec.co.uk/notes-domino-fp10-suggested-steps/.

Comment: Per ypour article, my issue was indeed that the plug-ins were disabled during the install.  By going to File > Applications > Application Management and clicking the show disabled icon at top I was able to see the ones that were disabled and enable them. This resolved my Issue. Thank you very much for your help and all your great articles.